# create JS cursor loop

Tags: javascript, loops, cursor

is there any solutions to make loop after mooving cursor on page in JS?

Comment: Please add more info in your question before it gets closed.

Comment: You've asked 13 questions and accepted answers to none of them?  That's not how SO works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html onmousemove="while(true);">
```